# Laravel 4 -Can you provide me top five data wrt their points and likes?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

I have one table **'Student'** in which there are several field `id`,`name`,`points`,`likes`,`email`.

I want list of top 5 student wrt to their maximum `likes` and maximum `points`.

I don't know which query to be used to get result.
Please help me.I am new in laravel.
I am using **mongodb** for database activity.

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution but it shoul work and it can be improved

```
 $topstudents = Student::orderBy('points' , 'asc')->orderBy('likes','asc')->take(5);
```

i usualy test before answering but im using a phone, i might test and improve the answer later if it is not what you want.

(there is an other way where you calculate the avrege of likes and points than take the top5 students with that avreage)